SourceTree and AWS Codecommit SSO connection
I have a project on AWS Codecommit and i use Jira SourceTree as a Git ui.
The company that i work give me an sso connection login but no iam user anymore (like before it worked).
Is there any solution so i can make SourceTree work again with AWS CodeCommit via an SSO login session ?
Right now when i make git pull windows require a login user... (Please look to the screenshot).

